# Create generic method to perform a database field update for a collection and run as a transaction

Tags: c#, generics

I have a model that looks like this

```
    public class Movie 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public boolean isDeleted { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a generic update method that looks like this.

```
    public async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T entity)
    {
        DbContext.Entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return ;
    }

     IEnumerable<Movie>
```

I want to be able to pass the IEnumerable above to the UpdateAsync method.
IEnumerable can sometime have one record or multiple records.

My goal is to update one field in  the table from this model (isDeleted)
i.e for every row in the collection with a specific ID update the isDeleted field to 1

How can I modify the UpdateAsync method above to do this and do it within a transaction.
If one fails or there is an error, roll back everything.

Comment: *"IEnumerable can sometime have one record or multiple records"*; Sounds like you need a loop.

Comment: I know I need a loop but how can i update just one field(isDeleted) from the model?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public async Task<T> UpdateAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities, Action<T> updateFunc)
{
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        updateFunc(entity);
    }

    DbContext.Entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entities);
    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

and call it like this:

```
await UpdateAsync(movieList, movie => movie.IsDeleted = true);
```

Essentially this *would* probably do what you expect it to. You pass it the list of entities which should be updated, and in addition you provide an `Action` which then transforms the entries as you want to.

However, in this case you might want to reconsider what you're trying to do with the updating function.

In case you want to just pass *ALL* your entities, you would probably have to introduce a way of selecting those with a certain ID (You mentioned something regarding only updating those with a specific ID). On the other side, in case you only pass eligible entities, this indicates that you were already doing some kind of filtering in advance, so you could think about redesigning your code and even doing the updating outside of the update function, leaving the update function to only do some plain database updating.

Essentially, in the end, whenever you want to have a generic functionality, but still want to do some custom things, `Func` and `Action` are your friends, as they allow you to "inject" functionality from the outside, without constraining your implementation.

Hope I got your question right.

Comment: What is updateFunc? Is that something I have to write?

Comment: Essentially it's an Action<T> in this case, so a function which returns void and accepts T as an argument. In my example I wrote a shorthand lambda for it (see the second parameter of the example UpdateAsync call)